# JS is firing multiple times and I dont understand why, need guidance

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a JS that does a call to another php and all it does is a DB update.

What I don't understand is why is it firing more then once!? and the weird thing it ONLY does this multi-fire on the first instance of the day, THEN it will behave as intended.

its ranged from firing off twice to 5 times, which it did this morning.

I've searched up and down for a solution and the only source I found that seemed like a I could fix the problem was here:

http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/

I tried each solution for a week to see if it would cure the issue and nothing.

So if anyone could explain to me WHY its doing it in the first place, maybe I can redo my search again for a solution.

Thank you in advance.

my JS:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#next',function(e) {

        //alert("You touched me!");

        window.patientName = $("#patientName").val();
        window.patientDOB = $("#patientDOB").val();
        window.gender = $("#pat_sex").val();
        window.race = $("#pat_ethnicity").val();
        window.age = $("#pat_age").val();

        // alert(patientName);
        // alert(patientDOB);
        // alert(gender);
        // alert(race);
        // alert(age);

        //alert("something logged");

        window.weight = $("#weight").val();
        window.height = $("#height").val();

        // alert(weight);
        // alert(height);


            //alert(preggo);
        if (gender === 'F') {
            if ($("[name=preggo]").is(":checked")) {
                preggo = $("[name=preggo]:checked").val();
            } else {
                preggo = "0";
            }
        }

        //alert(preggo);



        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('medical-problems');
        for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].checked){
                //alert(checkboxes[i].value);
                med_probs.push(checkboxes[i].value);
            }
        }


        var formData = {patientName1: patientName, patientDOB1: patientDOB, gender1: gender, race1: race, preggo1: preggo, age1: age, weight1: weight, height1: height, med_probs1: med_probs};

        if (weight === '' || height === '') {
            alert("Field(s) are Blank... Please enter data...");
            med_probs = [];
        }
        else {
            //alert("You touched me once!");
            //alert(document.getElementsByClassName("new-pat").length);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "formsubmit1.php", 
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    patient = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(patient['update']);
                    alert(data);
                    //alert("You touched me!");
                    $(".new-pat").css('display','none');
                    $(".new-pat-bp-form").css('visibility','visible');
                    $(".return-pat").css('display','none');
                    $(".return-pat-bp-form").css('visibility','visible');
                    //alert("You touched me! and returned!!!");
                    //alert(patientName);
                    //$('.new-pat')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post some code, maybe?

Comment: added my js, thanks in advance for any insight

Comment: And you're saying that

    $('#next').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){
        .... your function ....
    });

Didn't solve it?

Comment: e.PreventDefault(); and return false; at the end?

Comment: P - that is correct, tried that and it still multi-fired